# Validating boolean with Laravel Validation

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have a login form with

`username`, `password` and `remember me`

`remember me` is a checkbox (true or false).

How do I create the validation rule in Laravel?
http://laravel.com/docs/validation#basic-usage

The only relevant one it seems was `in` and you specify the values but the values in this case are booleans and using this method they would be specified as string?

`in:true,false`

Answer (score 24):

[There's a validator for `boolean`.](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-boolean) Assuming you're using one of the packages that simplifies model validation, e.g. [EsensiModel](https://github.com/esensi/model), it's as simple as adding the following to your `Model`:

```php
protected $rules = [
    'email'       => 'required|email',
    'password'    => 'required',
    'remember_me' => 'boolean',
];
```

Answer (score 5):

You may try something like this:

```
$rules = array('email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required');
$inputs = array(
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
);
$validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrorts($validator);
}
else {
    $remember = Input::get('remember', FALSE);
    if(Auth::attempt($inputs, !!$remember)) {
        // Log in successful
        return Redirect::to('/'); // redirect to home or wherever you want
    }
}
```

I've used `email` which is recommended but if you use `username` other than `email` then just change the `email` to `username` and in the rule for `username` use something like this:

```
'username' => 'required|alpha|min:6' // Accepts only a-z and minimum 6 letters
```

Comment: Thanks, clearly this looks pretty solid but anyway of actually using the validation class? (in my system I do validation before entering the controllers so it's a bit more involved to re-architect)

Comment: I really didn't get it, how can you validate before entering into the controller? Anyways, thanks for the thumbs up :-) maybe you may want to share a bit more about your system so we may discuss about it, I'm curious :-)